# OpenSSH libaudit.so missing

Tags: centos, ssh

I have a server running `CentOS 6.3`. I want to re-install openssh on my server. 
When I use `yum install openssh-server` I get this error:

```
Error: Package: openssh-server-6.1p1-5.el5.1.x86_64 (CentALT)
           Requires: libaudit.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I can't find a fix on the internet, how can I fix this?

Note:
Audit-libs is running the latest version

Thanks

Comment: well - is there a libaudit.X in /usr/lib ?

Comment: Which version of `audit-libs` are you running?

Comment: Please pastebin all of the output from yum

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it appears that you were using the CentOS / RHEL **5** version of the CentALT repo, but you say you are using CentOS 6.3.  You should remove the CentALT 5 repository from your system (found in /etc/yum.repos.d/) and switch to version 6 as described here: http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CentALT/readme.txt

Note: according to this page, http://tecadmin.net/top-5-yum-repositories-for-centos-rhel-systems/ , CentALT is no longer active.